# Formula for eigenvectors of 2x2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across [http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math21b2004/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/teaching/math21b2004/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html) and I know that for a $n \times n$ Matrix there are at most $n$ eigenvectors. So what happens when b **and** c are not zero? There can't be four eigenvectors so is it me or the website missing something?

Comment: If $b$ **and** $c$ are nonzero, then **in particular** $b$ is nonzero and we can apply the formula with $2$ eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two distinct eigenvalues, there is one eigenvector (up to scalar multiplication) associated with each, for a total of two.  If there is only one eigenvalue, it can be that all vectors in the space are eigenvectors, which gives two independent eigenvectors.  An example is the identity matrix.  There are matrices that have only one eigenvalue and one eigenvector.  An example is $$\begin {pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1 \end {pmatrix}$$ a possibility that the website does not mention.  In any case one would not consider there to be four eigenvectors.  f $b$ and $c$ are not both zero, the pairs given will be proportional to each other.

Answer (score -1):

Your statement "an $n \times n$ matrix has at most $n$ eigenvectors" is incorrect. In particular, if a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has an eigenvector $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\mu \mathbf{v}$ is also an eigenvector for all $\mu \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. So if there is an eigenvector, then there are infinitely many of them.

Thus, there being four eigenvectors for a $2 \times 2$ matrix is not a contradiction.

Comment: As you say, eigenvectors are defined up to scalar multiplication.  If the eigenvalues are distinct, there is only one eigenvector associated with each eigenvalue.  If the eigenvalues are the same, the eigenvectors are the whole space.  The site does not mention the case that there may be only one eigenvalue.

Comment: The site mentions all possible cases: if there is only one eigenvalue, then $L_1 = L_2$, using the sites' terminology. The formulas are still correct. One can only argue about the formulation "the eigenvectors are...", because "the" eigenvectors are not unique.